# Visual Studio Express 2012: Windows 8 designer won't start

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to design apps for Windows 8 in C#. But when I try to start the interface designer, it says "System.Security.SecurityException - Can't start the designer" or something like that. What is the meaning of this exception ?

Comment: Hi, Could you put the excact error, that will help other users to give you a better answer.